# Merge files and delete strings , which are same in the two text files

Tags: awk, merge

I have a problem with one code in AWK. I would like to delete string from second file, which are same with string in the first file.
For example:

1st file contain:

```
ACT
TTT
GTCA
CTG
```

2nd file contain:

```
GGGGTTT
CTGAGT
GTCAAAA
TTAAACT
```

An I would like to get in second file this:

```
GGGG
AGT
AAA
TTAA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {patt[$1]; next} 
    {
        for (p in patt) 
            if ($1 ~ p) {
                sub(p,"",$1)
                break
            }
        print
    }
' file1 file2
```

```
GGGG
AGT
AAA
TTAA
```